# Highlighted text in Xcode Version Editor makes text unreadable

Tags: xcode, version-control

Let's say you have downloaded a custom theme for Xcode, let's say [Darcula](https://github.com/jesseXu/xcode-theme-Darcula) or [Dracula](https://draculatheme.com/xcode/). It's beautiful and you are happy.

Then you open the Version editor (option-shift-command enter) (to compare code with older git revisions) and you can't see the revised code because it's beige-on-beige (or pale yellow to pale yellow, the point is there's no contrast and it is unreadable).

You can cry or check the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for ways to customize that particular setting (text highlighted in the right pane of the Version editor) but to no avail.

I then realized that **that particular color is actually the [complementary color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) of the regular text selection**, which was blue in my case.

Setting that color to a nice dark green made the text highlight in the version editor a nice purple.